# Android - Open Incoming File

Tags: android

I'm working on my first Android app, and I want to open and display PDF files. I have edited my `AndroidManifest.xml` file to allow a PDF file to be opened:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="application/pdf"/>
</intent-filter>
```

However, when I click on a pdf file from an app (mail, for example) and choose to open it with my app, my app just crashes. How do I configure my app to process the file and get its URL so that I can display it.

Comment: Please post your logcat and relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Opne Pdf File In Android

```
   String path = "/sdcard/AndroidUsersGuide-2.3.4.pdf";
   File targetFile = new File(path);
   Uri targetUri = Uri.fromFile(targetFile);

   Intent intent;
   intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setDataAndType(targetUri, "application/pdf");

   startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't this open a PDF file I have in another app? I want to open a PDF file from another app in my app.